# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'boto_region_name'

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, boto, amazon-sagemaker

I've been wrapped around this problem for a while and can't seem to understand where this issue is coming from. I'm deploying a model on Sagemaker and I get the error on this line of code:

`sm_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m4.2xlarge', endpoint_name=endpoint_name)`

Jupyter Notebook outputs the error below. Note: Line 269 isn't code in my Notebook, it is just a reference I get as a result of my model.deploy command above.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

    267             return self.image
    268 
--> 269         region_name = self.sagemaker_session.boto_region_name
    270         return create_image_uri(
    271             region_name,

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'boto_region_name'
```

Edit: This is just an example dataset that I'm using to create this pipeline. This is on a sagemaker notebook instance. I'm adding the entire code for clarification below.

```
from sagemaker.model import Model
from sagemaker.pipeline import PipelineModel
import boto3
from time import gmtime, strftime

import boto3
import s3fs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
sns.set()



import boto3
import sagemaker
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

# Using Amazon S3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
sage = boto3.client('sagemaker')

session = boto3.session.Session()    
sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()

# Get a SageMaker-compatible role used by this Notebook Instance.
role = get_execution_role()


#Upload file using AWS session
# S3 prefix

prefix = 'Scikit-keras-NLP-pipeline-Boston-Housing-example-June08-test1'


train_input = sagemaker_session.upload_data(
    path='housing.csv', 
    bucket=bucket,
    key_prefix='{}/{}'.format(prefix, 'train'))



from sagemaker.sklearn.estimator import SKLearn
output_dir = 's3://sagemaker-us-east-1-819182027957/Scikit-keras-NLP-pipeline-Boston-Housing-example-July08-test1/train'
model_dir = 's3://sagemaker-us-east-1-819182027957/Scikit-keras-NLP-pipeline-Boston-Housing-example-June08-test1/train'

script_path = 'Boston.py'

sklearn_preprocessor = SKLearn(
    entry_point=script_path,
    role=role,
    train_instance_type="ml.c4.xlarge",
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    output_path=output_dir)


sklearn_preprocessor.fit({'train': train_input,'model-dir':model_dir,'output-data-dir':output_dir})






from sagemaker.tensorflow.serving import Model
sagemaker_estimator = Model(model_data = 's3://' + sagemaker_session.default_bucket() + '/Scikit-keras-NLP-pipeline-Boston-Housing-example-June08-test1/train/Bostonmodel.tar.gz',
                                  role = role)


#####


scikit_learn_inference_model = sklearn_preprocessor.create_model()
#sagemaker_model = sagemaker_estimator.create_model()                     # Does Not have create_model method
sagemaker_model = sagemaker_estimator




model_name = 'Boston-inf-pipeline-July08-model' 
endpoint_name = 'Boston-inf-pipeline-July08-endpoint'


#Build Inference Pipeline
sm_model = PipelineModel(
    name=model_name, 
    role=role, 
    models=[
        scikit_learn_inference_model, 
        sagemaker_model],
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)

sm_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge', endpoint_name=endpoint_name)
```

Comment: can you include your code for creating `sm_model`? Also, what version of `sagemaker` is installed in your notebook?

Comment: Here is the code. Not sure which version of sagemaker is installed on the notebook, I'm using the notebook that launches from the AWS Sagemaker console. 

`#Build Inference Pipeline
sm_model = PipelineModel(
    name=model_name, 
    role=role, 
    models=[
        scikit_learn_inference_model, 
        sagemaker_model],
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)`

Comment: what is the code for creating the `sagemaker_session` variable? (sanity check: did you run the cell that instantiates that object?)

Comment: @lauren I've updated my question to show the code in it's entirety. In my notebook instance, I ran `print(session)' constantly to see if there's a point where session becomes undefined, but I always get `Session(region_name='us-east-1')` as an output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by your `sagemaker.tensorflow.serving.Model` not having a `sagemaker.session.Session` associated with it.

Add `sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session` to your Model instantiation:

```py
from sagemaker.tensorflow.serving import Model
sagemaker_model = Model(model_data='s3://' + sagemaker_session.default_bucket() + '/Scikit-keras-NLP-pipeline-Boston-Housing-example-June08-test1/train/Bostonmodel.tar.gz',
                        role=role,
                        sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. Been stuck on this for weeks and you just me get to the end of the tunnel. Much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you. I was confused, because the example in the documentation below is missing the sagemaker_session parameter: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/tensorflow/deploying_tensorflow_serving.html#providing-python-scripts-for-pre-pos-processing

Answer (score 0):

It means that something doesn't work right in your code. The variable `sagemaker_session` doesn't have a value assigned to it that you think it has. First check if the value of that variable is set correctly.